# Why does a range value not work for COUNTIFs statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to count the number of times on Sheet 1 ('1') there is any value ("*") in a certain range (X11:X730) when cell K2 = "A" AND when range B11:B730<19:00:00.

So for example:

- if K2 = A, B11 = 18:00:00 and there is a value in X11, it should give me 1.
- If K2 = A, B11 and B13 = 18:00:00 and there is a value in X11 and X13, it should give me 2.
- if K2 = A, B11 = 18:00:00 but there is no value in X11, it should yield 0.

This is the code I have:

```
=IF('1'!$K$2="A",COUNTIFS('1'!$B$11:$B$730,"<19:00:00",'1'!$X$11:$X$730,"*"),0)
```

It keeps yielding `#VALUE!`. If I have a single cell, not range (ex. `=IF('1'!$K$2="A",COUNTIFS('1'!$B$11,"<19:00:00",'1'!$X$11,"*"),0)`, I get the correct value.

I've also tried including all criteria in a COUNTIFS, no IF statement but no luck. It seems any range options in the code won't work and I don't know why.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I suspect you have some errors in the cells you are including in the range reference.

Comment: Is "Sheet 1" really named `1`?